# Kotlin default constructors

Tags: kotlin, jetbrains-ide

Are all this Kotlin snippets equivalent?

```
open class A
// A() - explicit call of A default constructor
class B : A()
```

using `super()` :

```
open class A

class B : A {
    constructor() : super()
}
```

using `super` :

```
open class A

class B : A {
    constructor() : super
}
```

nothing is specified:

```
open class A

class B : A {
    constructor()
}
```

So, what is a difference between `super` and `super()` in this cases, and if i understand right - last snippet implicitly calls `super()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a difference between super and super() in this cases

Nothing, both are the same

> Last snippet implicity calls super()

Yes, it does.

Comment: Thanks, as a result - all snippets are the same